# Disabling a button through jQuery doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my HTML code:

```
<div class='button' id='next'><a href='#'>Next</a></div>
<div class='button' id='prev'><a href='#'>Previous</a></div>
```

The button `next` must be disabled until something is selected

JQUERY code:

```
if (isNaN(selections[questionCounter])) {
    $('#next').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}
else {
    questionCounter++;
    displayNext();
}
```

I don't know how I can fix this.
I need something like that one
http://www.revillweb.com/demos/jQueryDisableButton/jqueryDisableButton.html

Comment: What is `selections`?

Comment: There is no standard way to 'disable' <a> or <div>
If you want to use the standard disable you should use <button> or <input>

Comment: What do you want to achieve with `disabling` a `div`? Hiding? Graying-out?

Comment: "I can show how" what?

Comment: I do not want to make it clickable and that he changed the transparency

Comment: You'll never be able to disable a button that is not a button :). Just use  e.preventDefault(); to disable the link. Change the CSS of the div (disabled with gray...or hide it).

Comment: The best you can do is to hide the div, or change it to  `button`or  `input`, or off the click using jquery

Answer (score 0):

Disable on a `div` is a non-sense.

You need to use a `button` in order to be able to disable it :

```
<button class='button' id='next'>Next</button>
<button class='button' id='prev'>Previous</button>
```

Also use JQuery to catch onClick event.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way to 'disable' `<a>` or `<div>`.
But you can [`.unwrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) the `<a>`.

```
<div class='button' id='next'><a href='#'>Next</a></div>
<div class='button' id='prev'><a href='#'>Previous</a></div>

<script>
if (isNaN(selections[questionCounter])) {
    $('#next').contents().unwrap();
}
else {
    questionCounter++;
    displayNext();
}
</script>
```

Comment: I tried adding the quotes. Still doesn't work.

I'll keep trying.  Any more ideas?

Comment: The quotes? What do you mean?

Comment: I need something like that one
http://www.revillweb.com/demos/jQueryDisableButton/jqueryDisableButton.html

Answer (score 0):

Like it was say you need to have `button` for use `disabled` property.

Other possibility if you realy want to stay with your `div` and `a` :

```
<script>
if (isNaN(selections[questionCounter])) {
    $('#next a').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); };
}
else {
    questionCounter++;
    displayNext();
}
</script>
```

Comment: // Click handler for the 'next' button
    $('#next').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Suspend click listener during fade animation
        if (quiz.is(':animated')) {
            return false;
        }
        choose();

        if (isNaN(selections[questionCounter])) {

           $('#next').contents().unwrap();
        }
        else {
             
            questionCounter++;
            displayNext();
        }
    }
    );
that I have already

Comment: Update your question in that case. And I think you have all necessary answer for doing what you have originally ask.